# Train full body in two days for four days straight

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, workout-routines, workout, gym

I have just started going to the gym and trying to lose weight (258 lbs ~= 117 kg) and I'm trying to make a schedule where I train my entire body twice a week.

Previously to this, I last trained a little over a year ago for 2.5 months and managed to lose around 30 lbs (15 kg) in this time, with a 6 day workout routine:

- Monday, Wednesday, Friday - training main muscle groups:

  - Legs
  - Chest & back
  - Biceps, triceps, shoulders
- Tuesday, Thursday - cardio: 20 minutes on treadmill
- Saturday: 3 mile run, 1 set max push-ups, 1 set max pull-ups

But my schedule has since changed and I can't go to the gym each day during the working week, so I'm forced to have most of my gym schedule in the weekend.

So far, I've finished week 1, going to the gym on Monday evening, Friday evening, Saturday morning and Sunday morning.

I'd like to keep this format as it fits well with my job & school schedule and would also like to hit all the muschles twice in these 4 days.

What I've considered is to make a 2-day split workout and repeat it for each 2 consecutive days (Friday & Saturday - full body workout #1, Sunday & Monday - full body workout #2).

My only problem is I don't know how to split my musche groups & my exercises into these 2 days, since I'm intending to repeat the exercises for the same body part two days later.

What I was considering was to split my schedule into:

- workout #1: - legs & chest
- workout #2: - back, biceps, triceps, shoulders

I have no experience of training other than the 2.5 months I have trained over a year ago, so I'm hoping to get some advice from more knowledgeable people.

Any help or guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to do a full workout twice in a week? can't you just focus on something else each day?

Comment: "hit all the muschles twice in these 4 days" There's a reason why most training schedules for beginners recommend a rest day between workouts. You need to rest your muscles to let them recover. I'm not sure if working out for four days straight is a good idea for a beginner.

Comment: If you really want to lose weight, I would start by *eating less*. It's much easier to eat a 500 calorie deficit (to lose ~1 lb/week) than it is to go on a 500 calorie workout every day (for me, about 5km of jogging). Eating less is *by far* a more effective way to lose weight.

Comment: It is eating less and training Stacey. The one compliment the other.

Comment: @Stacey Eating less is the main thing I am doing, having only two meals a day and maybe 1-2 snacks (fruits) in between with approximately a total of 8 hours eating window.

Comment: @speedyGonzales as someone who's recently lost over twenty kilos I can confidently say losing weight is mostly about diet. Even if you do only cardio every day (which op can't, only four days they said) it's unlikely you'd average 3-400 calories burnt a day. But with dieting you can create a 1000 calorie or more deficit fairly easily. And with a large calorie deficit you're not gonna be able to do too much cardio work.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Are you using a calorie tracker like myfitnesspal/fitbit where you log your intake every day? I find it a lot easier to track my intake that way or it's easier to over eat. I've been eating a 750 calorie deficit, working out 3x a week and have lost about a kg a week. You should be able to eat a 1000 calorie dificit at 100+ kg quite easily since it takes a lot to maintain that weight in the first place.

Comment: @Stacey I've been using something like this when I previously lost weight, but most of the foods I ate (local foods) did not appear in the lists. So, what I'm doing now is to eat foods which are as close to natural as possible and try not to over-eat(stuff my stomac with more than it needs). Also, not eating anything after 8PM.

Comment: I agree with Stacey, calorie counting is hugely important. In order to create a calorie deficit you need to know how much to put in. After a while you'll be able to approximate quite easily how much something is. The food need not be on the list, I did it on fitbit and just added a 100kj custom food so I just "ate" multiple of those to get the same calories as whatever I ate. Calorie counting is important because without it you may not realize just how many calories are in some foods. Even "healthy" and natural foods

Comment: @Aequitas It's difficult to say how many calories are in the food I eat, because they are cooked foods and local, whose calorie counts aren't on the web. Anyway, I have reduced my food intake (actually, cut down all of the sweets for a while, replaced sodas entirely with water, walking to replace "the car" as many times I can and incorporated physical activities in my schedule). Like I've mentioned in my previously, I don't eat a lot of food, I eat diversely and small amounts of each, for example I don't go all out on cheese, only because it's natural... since I know it's high calorie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are some general guidance I will give you :

1. Big Muscle groups need more time for recovery;
2. You should train antagonists in two different days(Antagonist and agonist muscles often occur in pairs, called antagonistic pairs. As one muscle contracts, the other relaxes= example - biceps and triceps ).
3. You need to do more reps with less weight if you want to loose weight.

If I were you I would start swimming. I know  this is not an answer to your question but you are over 100 kg (220lbs) and doing weight training might stress your joints if they aren't adapted for the weight. Swimming is a great full body exercice.

The same goes with cycling. It doesn't put stress on your joints too.

Running is a great exercice. I am runner myself and I run do 5k park competition every Saturday. If you are over 100 kgs It really hurts your knees.

My most important advice - find a group of friends or people, practicing some of the above sports, and joint them for motivation. It is more fun to train with someone then alone.

Comment: I made the exact plans as you mentioned, not running until I am 100kg or less. Last time I worked out and ran (I had 108 kg) after running 5k my knee joints hurt. After I lost more weight and wend under 100kg, I started not to feel this pain anymore and when I got to 93kg the pain was non-existent. Cycling is something I'm also incorporating into my workout (as a side-activity), so far having gone out once in this starting week. I try not to train with big weights, but smaller and do a lot of reps.

Comment: So, after all of your recommendations I am going to look for a suitable schedule to fit all of the muscle groups and hit them only once a week and will try to add more cardio-like training (cycling & football) in my off-days.

Comment: Some recommendation about eating : Try to avoid bread (I usually use just 1 slice at lunch time) and anything sweet after 6pm, no soft drinks (cola and ect). Actually I lost 5kg for a week due a stress recently and I cant recommend  big weight loss for short period of time. So put that into consideration too.

Comment: I'm avoiding bread, one-two slices once every few days, no more sweets, except fruits, no more soft drinks and .. so far, in one week of training (last week) with the mentioned schedule & extra activities (1 hour football game, 1 hour cycling) I lost 4 kg. I agree that such a great weight loss is not normal in a short time-frame, but in my scenario, where I am doing sports and not due to stress, I think most of my weight loss is water weight. I'll see how things progress in the coming weeks, but I expect my weight loss to stabilize somewhere around 1 - 1.5 kg per week, after 4-5 weeks training

Comment: Sounds good mate - 4-6 kg/ week is the way to go. Drink more water 2-3 liters a day and read about cheating day. I cant think for anything else. Wish you luck with your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I do drink a lot of water, more than 2 liters a day and also know about cheat day. I've also considered to remove all tempting foods for a while, while my metabolism starts and "speeds up" again and then, I believe I won't have to worry about having a cheat day, but could have small cheat-snacks when I feel the need (half-a bar of chocolate or something like this). Once again, thank you for the tips and good luck to you too if you're training.